# Cannot pass negative number as argument using fetch POST

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

Im trying to use fetch (method=POST) arguments like quantity=1 works fine:
[image]

but when it comes to negative numbers like quantity=-1 im getting status 400 response:

[image]

What is possible cause of this? Is it that website stop me before doing this or do i have to do it in other way?

Comment: What does a negative quantity mean?

Comment: This has nothing to do with fetch. The API you're calling doesn't allow negative quantities, so you get a validation error.

Comment: `fetch()` doesn't care what the parameters are, they're processed by the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page server (backend api) rejected my request because the conditions were not met. For example, if I sent a request to delete data that can only be deleted by the author.

(I tried here to "sell" negative numbers of things so i would receive it for free. Authors of this website/game predicted that some users would workaround/hack it like this hahah)